# SQL Server 2005 - T-SQL - how to get GUID as scalar function value

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I tried to write such kind of code as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DBO.GENCODE
AS
BEGIN

SELECT NEWID() AS GUID

END
GO
```

The thing is this procedure doesn't return a var value so I cannot use it for insert value. So my question is ... How to make possible code like

```
DECLARE @code VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @code = DBO.GENCODE()

    INSERT INTO TABLEA(CODE)
    VALUES(@code)
```

And this working snippet as a version...

```
DECLARE @code VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @code=(SELECT NEWID() AS GUID)
INSERT INTO TABLEA(CODE)
VALUES(@code)
```

?

Any useful comments are appreciated

Comment: this should work fine `INSERT TABLEA(CODE) VALUES (NEWID())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for now I am satisfied with this code because it works fine and gens a random code

```
DECLARE @code VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @code=(SELECT NEWID() AS GUID)
INSERT INTO TABLEA(CODE)
VALUES(@code)
```

But still I hope to get it working as a function. Maybe a little bit later then :)

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx

```
INSERT INTO TABLEA(CODE)
VALUES (NEWID())
```

Comment: what is the CODE fields type in the table schema? It should be uniqueidentifier.

Comment: The problem you are seeing is because the uniqueidentifier type returned by NEWID() is being type changed to be able to be put into a varchar field.  So you have two choices, you can alter your table to make the CODE field of type uniqueidentifier or you can do something like this in the values clause:  VALUES(CAST(NEWID() as VARCHAR(MAX)))

Comment: ,2user592704: if you insert a GUID which is 36 bytes long into a field, it should (a) be `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` (that's the "native" datatype for GUID's), or (b) if it has to be string, it should **definitely** not be `VARCHAR(MAX)` - `VARCHAR(36)` will be just as good!

Comment: @marc_s - if you're only ever storing a GUID, and if, as you say, you *have* to store it as a string, it's one occasion where I'd use `char` over `varchar`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: good point, since it's always going to be 36 characters long, there's really no point in having it be a `VARCHAR`. I typically only use `CHAR(x)` for x <= 5 - but here it totally makes sense - good catch!

Comment: well, actually, the snippet 3 worked fine as for me. But I want the expression as "SELECT NEWID() AS GUID" be able to invoke with a function name or something. But I didn't succeed to do that... That's why I am wondering the thing... I don't to write the expression each procedure or function... is it possible?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I do store it as a String but this is not the point... The question is how can I make a function of the expression?

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO TABLEA(CODE)
    EXEC DBO.GENCODE
```

I'm answering the question literally because I would assume there is more complicated logic inside the stored procedure than this.

Edit re the question edit: You either have to use the `INSERT`/`EXEC` trick that I show above, or use a scalar UDF. It's not possible to do that using a stored procedure.

Comment: Can it be a function to invoke "select newid() as guid"?

Comment: @user592704: See the other answer. If all you want to do is put a new guid value into a column, that will work. I had assumed you were doing something more complicated. If you want to call it as a function, as I state in my answer, you cannot do this using a stored procedure.

Comment: Yes, I want to use a function to get the @code value but I didn't make it... It seems to be a table returns or something which makes an error as it is invoked

Comment: @user592704: You'll have to use INSERT/EXEC -- if you need to do things to the values before they go into a physical table, you can do INSERT/EXEC into a table variable: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx

Comment: I do use INSERT and EXEC with this code but I want to get the AS GUID with a function call... For example: @code=guid_fn()

Comment: @user592704: Then you have to use a scalar user-defined function (UDF), or simply call `NEWID()` directly (i.e., `SET @code = NEWID()`).